CE/FCC certification for RF module only
I've seen many discussions about selling electronic devices with certified modules inside, but I haven't found any that address whether companies need to certify a module if it’s not intended to be an "end product".
For example, I'm developing a custom ESP32 module (from scratch) with specific functionality that existing certified modules don’t offer. If I plan to sell this module in the EU or USA, do I need to certify it, even though it’s just a component meant to be used as part of a larger device, not a standalone product?
From my understanding of the regulations, the responsibility for certification lies with the manufacturer of the final device.
What legally appropriate terminology should I use in the product description to inform buyers that the product is not certified when selling it in my online store?
Any clarification on certification requirements for such modules would be greatly appreciated.


From my understanding of the regulations, the responsibility for certification lies with the manufacturer of the final device.

The responsibility lies on the party that places the device on the market. I'm not a lawyer but I think the legislation might make a difference between selling the device to select customers or making it available to anyone through for example an online store. Because if you sell it to select customers then you will know that the other party is a professional company buying the device for the purpose of further product development. And not some random hobbyist putting the PCBA in their christmas tree.
The EU directives explicitly make a difference between "placing on the market" and "putting into service". From the Radio Equipment Directive, article 2:

(9) ‘making available on the market’ means any supply of radio equipment for distribution, consumption or use on the Union market in the course of a commercial activity, whether in return for payment or free of charge;
(10) ‘placing on the market’ means the first making available of radio equipment on the Union market;
(11) ‘putting into service’ means the first use of radio equipment in the Union by its end-user;

So if you put it on the market (through an online store etc) then you need CE/FCC approval. There exists an exemption for prototype/demo/evaluation boards, for the purpose of R&D and prototyping etc. But you can't really claim that your board is such a prototype if you sell the product online to anyone.
Furthermore, selling a board with RF features without even providing information about approved reference antennas probably won't sit well with the customers. Since competing modules will provide reference antennas that have been used during testing, they will offer a better product than one which just passes along that responsibility onto the customers using the module.
If you on the other hand test the product using one or several antennas, then you have an available reference design and you also get a free pass in case someone decides to use your module with a different antenna than the one you recommended and end up violating EMC regulations.

Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. For instance, consider this product: https://www.speedybee.com/speedybee-tx-ultra/. It operates on the 5.8GHz frequency and emits 800mW of power. Not only does it lack proper certifications, but it also exceeds legal power limits. While this might be expected from a Chinese online store, the same product can be found in European e-shops, such as this one: https://www.drone-fpv-racer.com/en/speedybee-tx800-8885.html .
Many FPV model stores seem to sell uncertified parts without any issue... Does it mean they all break the law?

@user3500960 Yes, companies from the far east routinely put things to market in the european union that are breaking the laws.

@user3500960 Looks illegal indeed. The bare minimum would be the CE mark and a Declaration of Conformity made available. In case the product can't physically fit the CE mark then there are alternative methods, but they always need to provide a Declaration of Conformity. However, they might not have made any claims of suitability for the EU or American markets, so if you bought it from them and imported it to the EU/Americas, then you are the one held responsible for the non-conformance.

@user3500960 Like... if some muppet buys a module from that site and decides to fly the drone close to an airport, hospital or military installation and cause EMI problems for them... that's probably considered serious enough a crime to end up in jail. Not only the drone pilot but the ones who sold the Chinese crap to them as well.

@user3500960, This product is illegal and the website can be held responsible in France. To become legal it must sell only to the professional to enter the excéptions of the directives RED, EMC and LVD (see my message : Can you sell a non-certified module? Yes, if you fall within exception 4. Custom-built evaluation kits destined for professionals to be used solely at research and development facilities for such purposes.)

@Vincent I find it hard to argue that a product like that drone system is sold solely for R&D and prototyping. It would have to be marketed as "evaluation board" or the like. So the exemptions from RED et al do not apply.

@Lundin, I think marketing  as a “evaluation board” or similar is not a sufficient condition for exemption from the RED directive and other directives if you sell to non-professional customers. For example, Arduino boards have to provide their certificate of conformity because they sell to private individuals. https://docs.arduino.cc/static/cc5634f96c38cb5f5f311f604e12ed07/Arduino_A000066-DoC_CE.pdf
I agree with you that it would be difficult to say that this product is intended for R&D purposes.

How about SDRs that are sold to all kind of amateurs without any certifications?

@user3500960 Same deal, needs CE marking. Radio amateurs don't need a license within their bands, but the radio device used need to conform to the radio standards and band restrictions.


but I haven't found any that address whether companies need to certify a module if it’s not intended to be an "end product".

In fact, this is a very rare case. In the general case anyone who buys a module for their end product needs to be sure that their certification won't fail because of the module. Meanwell's power modules, for example, are certified to ensure that their customer does not fail certification of the power supply part.
In the European Union, there are 3 mandatory standards: LVD, EMC and RED.
Exceptions to the LVD directive are listed in Appendix II : https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32014L0035#d1278e32-369-1
Exceptions to the RED directive are listed in Appendix I : https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32014L0053#d1e32-95-1
Exceptions to the EMC directive are listed in Chatper I, Art 2 : https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32014L0030#d1e527-79-1
Can you sell a non-certified module?
Yes, if you fall within exception 4. Custom-built evaluation kits destined for professionals to be used solely at research and development facilities for such purposes.
Will a customer be able to design a finished product with a non-certified module?
He takes the risk, but in reality nobody does.
